# There is no module Jinja2

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, jinja2

When i try make this code:

```
  from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment, Template

    # generate an html-report
    templateEnv = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')))
    template = templateEnv.get_template("report_temp.html")
    user = 'dear user'
    outputText = template.render(user = user)                             
    # print(outputText)

    dtm = str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ".html"
    with open(dtm, "w") as f:
     f.write(outputText)
```

On my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04) it works well (i havn't installed Jinja2 even). But when i make it on server (Ubuntu 14.04) or docker container it's the mistake:

```
  from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment, Template
ImportError: No module named 'jinja2'
```

I tried to install virtual env and to install jinja2 under it, but doesn't work. When i make `pip list` there show that jinja has been installed.

In what can be the reason? How to fix it?

Comment: Try with pip3 instead of pip

Comment: maybe in another virtual env you checked 'pip list' and on another you run a code ?

Answer (score 0):

It was needed for installing jinja2 into the directory with pip3. Thanks